# How to categorize text into groups in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a vector of words

```
c('Apple','Orange','Apple','Carrot','Onion','Onion')
```

I want to categorize them in

```
list('fruit' = c('Apple', 'Orange'),
'vegetable' =  c('Carrot','Onion')
```

The output I am looking for is

```
c('fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetable', 'vegetable', 'vegetable') .
```

My current approach is to convert each of them to `data.table` and use `merge` to get the categories. Is there any other simpler solution?

Comment: In your simple case you could stick with the vectors. I would try `l <- c('Apple', 'Orange', 'Carrot','Onion') ; m <- rep(c("fruit", "vegetable"), each =  2) ; m[match(x, l)]`. I think we have plenty of dupes for this one.

Comment: The answer by @Marek in the linked dupe should be fine here since you already have a lookup list. And it's certainly clean ("This is by far the easiest way", J. Ulrich)

Comment: ["Character matching provides a powerful way to make lookup tables"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications) (appears also in the linked dupe); perhaps even simpler, _if_ your lookup table was structured differently.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Indeed the second link gives the simplest possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one alternative

```
x <- c('Apple','Orange','Apple','Carrot','Onion','Onion') 
lst <- list('fruit' = c('Apple', 'Orange'),
'vegetable' =  c('Carrot','Onion'))
with(stack(lst), ind[match(x, values)])
# [1] fruit     fruit     fruit     vegetable vegetable vegetable
```